Prove the orthogonality of the Legendre Polynomial from the recursion only.
It's known that the Legendre Polynomials follow the recursion:
$$P_n(x)=\frac{2n-1}{n}xP_{n-1}(x)-\frac{n-1}{n}P_{n-2}(x)$$
with
$$P_0(x) = 1, P_1(x)=x$$
Now I am finding an elementary method to prove the orthogonality of the series only based on the recursion.
By the induction I can get that the polynomial is even when n is even, and odd when n is odd.
Now the only problem is that I can't verify that the inner product of $P_n$ and $P_{n-2}$ is zero. Is there any simple method which can prove it only by the recursion without using the theory of differential equation?
Any hint will be helpful.
Thank you in advance!

@coffeemath $[ -1,1 ]$ is the interval. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials#Orthogonality_and_completeness

It's my fault. The inner product is $\int_{-1}^{1}f(x)g(x)dx$.

I'm sorry to give a wrong recursion because of the typo of my book and I correct it now.

The following is my idea:
To verify that $<Pn, P_{n-2}>=0$, according to the Schmit Orthogonalization, I need to prove $||P_n||=\frac{2}{2n+1}$ or $\frac{<P_n,P_n>}{<P_{n-1},P_{n-1}}=\frac{2n-1}{2n+1}$
But in the induction, when I deal with the norm, I need to use the result that the inner product of $P_{n+1}$ and $P_{n-1}$ is zero, which hasn't been proved in this step.
That's what blocks me.
